# Upload Destination Catalog through Facebook UI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I own a facebook page for a travel website. Is there a way to upload Destination Catalog through facebook UI (for showing dynamic ads)? I was only able to find a way through Catalog API and it's not working for me. ([Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-ads-for-travel/catalog#create-destination-catalog))

```
 Request: curl -F 'name=Destination Catalog' -F 'vertical=destinations' -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/<BUSINESS_ID>/product_catalogs

 Response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) The app is not whitelisted to use this API","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"H5799z95qIa"}}
```

Any suggestion or work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your own Facebook App that you've configured to use the Marketing API and generated a token with the `business_management` permission.

There is a guide to getting started on the Marketing API here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

Using a System User may also be the easiest thing:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/